# jQuery not animating color change

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMJWS/

I want to make the text turn red on click, but it's not working for some reason:

html:

```
<div id = 'text'>hi</div>
```

css:

```
#text {
    color:black;
}
```

js:

```
function turnred() {
    $("#text").animate({color: 'red'}, 400);
}

$('#text').click(function() {
    turnred();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work with color animation you need to include `JQuery UI`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMJWS/1/)**

Comment: ahh got it. (i just used `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` from the jqueryui site). thanks!